# Could you train TensorFlow to assess pronunciation?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have a language learning app and would like to detect the pronunciation of users saying certain words and sentences.

If I can provide a 1000 user audio files, each with a rating out of 100 of how good the pronunciation is, could I predict a score out of 100 of how good the pronunciation is?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not, this is a very general question though...  I would read up on how to vectorize audio first. [These guys](http://www.hexahedria.com/2015/08/03/composing-music-with-recurrent-neural-networks/) used a neural network to generate audio data, maybe you could look at how they took in data and do something similar.  Then once you vectorize it, pass the vector as input and score as the label.